# Why was the scene cut without any reply from Zakharov?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, red-sparrow

In *Red Sparrow* Zakharov says to his assistant after he had got some information via phone:

> Zakharov: No loose ends. Nothing that can come back on the president.
>
> Assistant: And the girl?
>
> **(cuts to new scene)**

Why was the scene cut without any reply from Zakharov?

Comment: I didn't see the film yet, but going with Snow's answer, it may have been cut that way to generate suspense, because then you don't know what the intended outcome is. Jumping into another scene, especially if it's high adrenaline definitely is good way to keep the thrills going.

Comment: @DarthLocke 's guess is correct, from my recollection.  We know Zakharov may be an ally or an enemy to "the girl", but we don't *really* know which it is.  There's a lot of second-guessing people's motives in this film; it's a recurring theme.  If we had heard his answer, one way or the other, it would tell the audience if he was really on her side (or not.)  So, they avoided doing that to keep us guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recall this scene in the film, but I'm just assuming here that it was a jump-cut to demonstrate **what was happening** with Dominka rather than have this as part of the dialogue.